# How do I enforce a server-generated timestamp to a document in Firestore?

Tags: security, server, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

Let me begin by saying I just started with Firestore.

I am building a messaging application in React Native with Firestore. When a user sends a message to another user, a document is created containing the information of the message.

```
{
 sender : 'fb-userid-qsdf'
 content : 'hello',
 created : firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
}
```

What I don't understand, is how I can make this tamper-proof. It seems to me that a user could alter this message and send any timestamp as a creation date, rather than the request for the server value that I programmed.

And even if there were a way to fix this problem, it still seems there would be a security flaw: every user has write access to /messages/{messageId} as long as the 'sender' property of the {messageId} document is the same as the user's id. So couldn't a user write malicious code that bypasses my function and insert messages with arbitrary timestamps?

There has to be something I'm missing but I can't seem to find the answers anywhere. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think one solution for that is to move your message creation to a cloud function where you only access a sender and a content then its up to the function to provide the timestamp. that way your `created` field is not coming from the client side but generated from your cloud function.

Comment: You should know that `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is used only with Realtime Database, not Firestore.  Firestore uses a different constant value.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue.html#servertimestamp

Comment: You can enforce  FieldValue.serverTimestamp on a particular document field in security rules as show in the duplicate.  Alternately, you can force the client to make changes through some backend you control, and force the timestamp securely from there.